# Some environments conflict with current Glimpse async support

Tags: c#, glimpse

I have just installed Glimpse in my application via NUGET.
I am getting this exception:
[image]

I do not know why this is happening, I am none the wiser looking in the Github reference and I do not know where in the web.config file to set DisableAsyncSupport = true. Is it really a good idea to disable this anyway?

EDIT

I found that I can set the following in AppSettings in the web.config file;

```
<add key="Glimpse:DisableAsyncSupport" value="true" />
```

This stops the exception and it also stops Glimpse from working.

Comment: What version of Glimpse do you have installed? Are all the packages running the newest version?

Comment: I installed the latest version, Glimpse MVC 1.5.3. The Package.Config is updated (if that is what you are asking)